# I am looking to run an ARIMA on Time Series data. Everything in my code works up until the point where I forecast. Below is my data, code, and error

Tags: r, time-series, arima, forecast, autoplot

I am getting this error:

> Error in switch(names(interval), day = "days", hour = "hours", minute = "mins",  :
> EXPR must be a length 1 vector**

When I am forecasting my ARIMA using the following line of code:

```
fcast = forecast(fit_arima,h=24)
```

I have tried troubleshooting this error on my own but after a couple hours I figured I would ask for some helps from the experts!

Here is [my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLOpW.png), and below is my full script:

```
install.packages("fpp2")
install.packages("fable")
\#Install fpp2 package for Time Series data
library(fpp2)
library(fable)

\#Clear All Variables in workspace
rm(list = ls())

data = data.table(read.csv("spft.csv"))
\#Read DT

\#Declare this as time series data (Time Series Variable = Y)
Y = ts(data[,2],start=c(2019,1),frequency = 12)

\###########################################################################

# Preliminary Analysis

\###########################################################################

# Time Plot

autoplot(Y) +
ggtitle("Time Plot: Sparefoot Rental Rate Per Month") +
ylab("Adjusted for Inflation")

\#Data has a strong trend. Investigate Transformations

# Take the first difference of the data to remove the trend

DY = diff(Y)

# Time Plot Difference Data

autoplot(DY) +
ggtitle("Time Plot: Sparefoot Rental Rate Per Month") +
ylab("Adjusted for Inflation")

# Series appears trend-stationary, use to investigate seasonality

ggseasonplot(DY) + ggtitle("Seasonal Plot: Change in Sparefoot Street Rates") +
ylab("Sparefoot Street Rates")

\#The data is very seasonal - increase especially during the summertime May-August

# The data is very seasonal - decrease especially during August-Jan

# Let's look at another seasonal plot, the subseries plot

ggsubseriesplot(DY)

\#Average Changes in February,May,June,July,August are all positive
\#Average Changes in Jan,Mar,April,Sep,October,November,Dec are all negative

\##############################################################

# Our series, Y, has trend and seasonality

# To remove the trend, we take the first difference

# The first difference series still has seasonality

# Forecast with various methods.

######################################

#### 

# Use a benchmark method to forecast.

# Let's use seasonal naive method as our benchmark.

# y_t = y\_{t-s} + e_t

# We want to use the difference data because have a trend

#### 

fit = snaive(DY) # Residual SD = 2.86
print(summary(fit)) # This model is working well, The ACF model is within the 95% CI
checkresiduals(fit) # The residuals fit nicely in the bell curve

##### 

# Fit ETS Method

##### 

fit_ets = ets(Y)
print(summary(fit_ets))
checkresiduals(fit_ets)

# This model is also solid

##### 

# Fit an ARIMA model

##### 

fit_arima = auto.arima(Y,d=1,D=1, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE, trace = TRUE)
#this is fitting an arima, including difference (d=1), including seasonality (D=1)

# this fits the best arima model

print(summary(fit_arima))
#take square root of squared error
checkresiduals(fit_arima)

sqrt(4.526) #2.12
#This is the best model for this data

##############################

# Forecast with ARIMA model

#############################

fcast = forecast(fit_arima,h=24)
autoplot(fcast)
```

## Edit

Data set posted in comments as a data.frame.

```
df1 <-
structure(list(Time = structure(c(17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 
18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 
18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18506, 18536, 
18567, 18597, 18628, 18659, 18687, 18718, 18748, 18779, 18809, 
18840, 18871, 18901, 18932, 18962, 18993, 19024, 19052, 19083, 
19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 19236, 19266, 19297, 19327), class = "Date"), 
    UnitPrice = c(84, 86.96, 87.26, 85.28, 84.29, 92.35, 91.26, 
    91.34, 89.95, 89.25, 87.49, 83.17, 82.64, 84.17, 80.49, 79.57, 
    80.46, 86.13, 89, 94, 94, 95, 94, 95, 93, 97, 97, 97, 99, 
    110, 112, 115, 114, 115, 113.8, 111.29, 110.66, 111.31, 112.58, 
    112.67, 112.34, 119.18, 122.15, 119.14, 114.37, 111.39, 108.09, 
    103.22)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -48L))

Y <- ts(df1[, 2], start = c(2019, 1), frequency = 12)
```

Comment: Unit Price
84.000
86.960
87.260
85.280
84.290
92.350
91.260
91.340
89.950
89.250
87.490
83.170
82.640
84.170
80.490
79.570
80.460
86.130
89.000
94.000
94.000
95.000
94.000
95.000
93.000
97.000
97.000
97.000
99.000
110.000
112.000
115.000
114.000
115.000
113.800
111.290
110.660
111.310
112.580
112.670
112.340
119.180
122.150
119.140
114.370
111.390
108.090
103.220

Comment: Time
1/1/2019
2/1/2019
3/1/2019
4/1/2019
5/1/2019
6/1/2019
7/1/2019
8/1/2019
9/1/2019
10/1/2019
11/1/2019
12/1/2019
1/1/2020
2/1/2020
3/1/2020
4/1/2020
5/1/2020
6/1/2020
7/1/2020
8/1/2020
9/1/2020
10/1/2020
11/1/2020
12/1/2020
1/1/2021
2/1/2021
3/1/2021
4/1/2021
5/1/2021
6/1/2021
7/1/2021
8/1/2021
9/1/2021
10/1/2021
11/1/2021
12/1/2021
1/1/2022
2/1/2022
3/1/2022
4/1/2022
5/1/2022
6/1/2022
7/1/2022
8/1/2022
9/1/2022
10/1/2022
11/1/2022
12/1/2022

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75681301/edit) with the output of `dput(data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`.

Comment: Added Dput in the question Rui!

Comment: Sorry, I meant your data, you have posted the function `data`.

Comment: Use `forecast::forecast(fit_arima, h = 24)` instead. And you are missing an `"a"` in the next instruction, it should be `autoplot(fcast)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you Rui, I added the 'a' to the auto(fcast). However, the original question still stands when trying to create a forecast and then autoplot it. The same error message still occurs. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't load the fable package. You don't use it, and it might be causing a clash with the forecast function if you're using an old version of fable.